# Various regions of fluid flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics

[image]
In the image above, there is this plot between sound velocity and flow velocity. I want to check if my interpretation of the plot is right or not. Here are my observations:

(1) The c-a plot is a plot of how speed of sound varies with the variation of speed of **fluid** (**through which the sound is propogating**).

(2) When the flow speed is zero (stagnation condition) the speed of sound is maximum, as 'c' increases 'a' decreases and at maximum flow speed, **speed of sound becomes zero**.

Does motion of the medium itself affect the speed of sound propogating through it? S0 far, i had only read about density, nature of medium as the parameters affecting speed of sound, so this is where my confusion arises from.

Image reference: Fundamentals of compressible flow - SM Yahya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation of the plot is correct: it is showing how the local speed of sound in the flow varies with the speed of the gas, assuming ideal gas and adiabatic conditions. You are also correct that, as the flow speed increases, the local speed of sound decreases, until it reaches zero. In practice, this sets a maximum limit that the speed of the flow can attain, for a given stagnation enthalpy:

$$c_{max}=\sqrt{2h_0}$$

The motion of the fluid does indeed affect the speed of sound waves moving through it. If you consider equation (2.19), for a fixed stagnation enthalpy, if c increases, then the enthalpy (and hence the temperature) must decrease. Because $a=\sqrt{\gamma RT}$, this decrease in temperature causes the local speed of sound to decrease.

Comment: The last part was very very helpful. Thanks a lot.